# Reference all tabs with a specific word in COUNTIF statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-custom-function

Basically, I am trying to make a master tab that adds up all of the data from all the other tabs. These tabs are weekly breakdown numbers for ad statistic numbers, so there is a new tab added every week. Here is what every tab looks like. [image] The only option I have in mind to accomplish this is adding the new tab name to the formula (to be written) every time I create a new tab. However, I am wondering if there is a way to reference all tabs that contain a hyphen "-" because they are all titled with a date range separated by a hyphen. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe even with some sort of helper column on the to-be-created master tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SHEETLIST() {
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;
  out[0] = [ "NAME" , "#GID" ];
  for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i] = 
  [sheets[i-1].getName() , sheets[i-1].getSheetId() ];
  return out
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}}
```

```
=QUERY(SHEETLIST(TODAY()), "select Col1 where Col1 contains '-'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is fantastic! How do I get SHEETLIST() to update automatically when I add a new tab? Also, how could I format the tabs pulled from SHEETLIST() into an array to use with a query formula? EX: =QUERY(['tab 1'!A:A; 'tab 2'!A:A; etc.], "select....")

Comment: it (should) recalculate on a daily basis with `today()` inside, or by manually crippling the formula and then re-correcting it.

Comment: Ah okay that's perfect. Did you have any idea how to accomplish the second part of my comment? I've hit a wall with this.